# How can I generate a file with a name of length X in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, fopen, archive

I am writing the code of a program that manages plain text files. The question is how can I generate a file, using `fopen()`, with a String whose length is `X`.

What I mean with `X` is that the user can type just one letter as the name of the file `("a.txt")`, but he could also type a very long name `("this_is_my_super_new_file_bla_bla_bla.txt")`.

I am trying to do it with a linked list, but I do not know how to pass the char part of the node of the linked list to the argument of `fopen()`.

Is there another way to do it? The only thing I do not want to do is to restrict the lenght of the name. If I do it, I would have to reserve memory since the beginning, and it would make my program heavier.

Comment: Count the length of the list, `malloc` an appropriate chunk of memory, copy the `char`s from the list into the array, one after the other, add a 0-terminator, and pass that to `fopen`.

Comment: More seriously, use `getline` to get the file name from the user if you can assume POSIX. If not, roll your own get-input-and-allocate-as-needed routine.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do? What does the string contain, and what should the file name be?

Comment: See if you can find an implementation of e.g. [`mkstemp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html) and see how they do it? Or if it's available, why not use that directly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a string (`char *`) with the file name and you would like to add the ".txt" extension, then you could do something like this:

```
char *input = "new_file_name";
char *filename = malloc((strlen(input) + 5) * sizeof(char));
sprintf (filename, "%s.txt", input);
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
free(filename);
```